# How can I access videojs.SeekBar and ControlBar in version 5?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I want to port [this plugin](https://github.com/danielcebrian/rangeslider-videojs) to the new videojs version 5. I updated most of the plugin to fit into the new `videojs.extend()` requirements and updated the public functions declarations.

The part I'm stuck on is when you try to load the new components into videojs:

```
 //Range Slider Time Bar
 videojs.SeekBar.prototype.options_.children.RSTimeBar = {};
 //Panel with the time of the range slider
 videojs.ControlBar.prototype.options_.children.ControlTimePanel = {};
```

If I understand it correctly (I am having some doubts), it is extending specific parts of videojs in order to contain the plugin components.

The problem is that `videojs.SeekBar` and `videojs.ControlBar` are undefined and I don't know the right way to access them in v5 (or to create these empty objects if it isn't how you do it anymore). There is also no indication in the videojs wiki article "[5.0 changes details](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/5.0-Change-Details)"

[The full code is available here.](https://jsfiddle.net/hg4vp6we/4/). The faulty lines are 421 and 422

---

**EDIT**

I can get rid of the error if I replace these lines with those:

```
videojs.getComponent("SeekBar").prototype.options_.children.RSTimeBar = {}; //Range Slider Time Bar
videojs.getComponent("ControlBar").prototype.options_.children.ControlTimePanel = {}; //Panel with the time of the range slider
```

but in the plugin constructor function, I can't find back the components:

```
  //components of the plugin
  var controlBar = player.controlBar;
  var seekBar = controlBar.progressControl.seekBar;
  this.components.RSTimeBar = seekBar.RSTimeBar; //is undefined
```

When I explore the videoJs object, in my debugger, I can indeed find `player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar` but it has no sub-object called `RSTimebar` except in `options_.children`. It makes sense since it is where I defined it. However, I don't know why in the version 4 I can find it but not in the version 5.

---

**EDIT 2**

I notices that the `RSTimebar` in `options_.children` array was inserted as an object instead of a pair of index/string. So I changed my lines to this:

```
    videojs.getComponent("SeekBar").prototype.options_.children.push("RSTimeBar"); //Range Slider Time Bar
videojs.getComponent("ControlBar").prototype.options_.children.push("ControlTimePanel"); //Panel with the time of the range slider
```

Result: the plugin is correctly loaded with one warning per component:

> VIDEOJS: WARN: The RSTimeBar component was added to the videojs object
>   when it should be registered using videojs.registerComponent(name,
>   component)

I just need to figure out the proper and simplest way to correctly load the components now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to update the plugin thanks to [a commit](https://github.com/mikaelnousiainen/rangeslider-videojs/commit/9e98433e881e18285301b6026621ef5588094917) where most of the work was done.